# Can object have 2 parents in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a comment object, and I use polymorphic association, so it can belongs to many other objects. But I also want them to belong to users.

Now I can, call `comment.comment_owner` and I get the object that was commented by this comment.

As for the user I have a `user_id` field in the comment object, I pass the user id through the form. But when I try to get owner user by `comment.user` I get an error. Right now I`m getting user by User.find(comment.user_id). But this looks bad.

Is there a way to pass the user id. So I can get User owning a comment by `comment.user`

My associations:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment_owner, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :comment_owner
end

class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :comment_owner
end
```

Comment: provide your association, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: So simple, it is mostly so simple. When I was doing the polymorphic association, I have forgotten that it can be also associated normal way. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my opinion `comment_owner` is not a good name for what you're designing here. Comment owner would suggest an ownership relation (rather a person or someone). I'd rather call it `commentable` as these object are being commented on.

If this relation is meant to be a polymorphic then you should have `commentable_type` and `commentable_id` (or `comment_owner_type` and `comment_owner_id` if you really prefer the original) as `polymorphic => true` expects to have those two fields (named as: *relation_name*`_type` and *relation_name*`_id`).

If you then have a Comment object you get the user commented by calling `comment.commentable` (or `comment.comment_owner` in case you decide to keep your naming).

[EDIT]
As you said, you want to have two parents. If I get this right you just want to have two **relations** - this means that if you just modify your code to:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :notes, class_name: 'Comment'
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

You will have your polymorphic relation as well as the ownership.

Comment: As for the name, comment_owner refers to the object that was commented by this comment, (I have comment_owner_type and comment_owner_id fields). Thats why when I call comment.comment_owner I get commented object, and I wanted to also have an option to call comment.user to get author of the comment.